# CSS is not loading in Iframe fancy box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a fancybox iframe and css is written on parent page. but css is not working in Fancy box but when i change to ajax it is working properly.

Comment: When asking a question please provide some code - here would be some  jsfiddle good.

Answer (score 1):

If you have something in iframe you have to set the css for the page inside it too, If u want it to work. The css for the main page works just for the main page not for the iframe content.